# Will Instance Refresh in salesforce effect the marketing cloud connector integration

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, marketing-cloud-connect

We have NA Instance refresh in salesforce in the coming weeks, so after refresh if salesforce Org ID changes, does it have any impact on marketing cloud connector as Marketing cloud uses salesforce ORG id to integrate.

If it impact what are the pre- refresh steps that i have to take care in terms of marketing cloud

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would not be an issue after refresh if salesforce Org ID changes you simply need to go to your marketing cloud admin panel (email>>admin>salesforce integration) and disconnect the account and connect it again, It'll automatically sync with the fresh instance.

It's not necessary but I would recommend you to backup all salesforce data extensions.