# Marketing Cloud Connector not working after Salesforce sandbox refresh

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

We had a Salesforce sandbox integrated with Marketing Cloud and refreshed the sandbox without previously disconnecting the Marketing Cloud Connector. Now we see this error message:

> *InvalidParameterException: Whoops! Marketing Cloud Connect does not have access to the selected object. Contact your administrator to
> enable objects for Marketing Cloud Connect triggered sends.*

Is there anything we can do now to solve this issue? Or do we have to contact the support?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000268883&language=en_US&type=1 regarding the  remote site setting named "MetadataAPI".

Also have a look at: [Will Instance Refresh in salesforce effect the marketing cloud connector integration](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/169611/will-instance-refresh-in-salesforce-effect-the-marketing-cloud-connector-integra)

Regards